# how to draw graphics in JPanel out of paintComponent method?

Tags: java, swing, graphics, paintcomponent

i need to draw some lines in a `JPanel` in Java, I'm trying to draw them in another method outside the `paintComponent()` method to call it from another class but i faced a problem because drawing graphics need a `Graphics` object, i tried using `this.getGraphics()` but didn't work for me :

```
public class Panel extends JPanel{
    public void drawLine(int x1, int y1, int x2, int y2){
        this.getGraphics().drawLine(x1, y1, x2, y2);
    }
}
```

any suggessions please ?

Answer (score 2):

> "any suggessions please ?"

Keep a list of [`Line2D`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/awt/geom/Line2D.Double.html) objects in the `Panel` class. (`List<Line2D>`)

Iterate through the list in the `paintComponent` method

```
Graphics2D g2 = (Graphics2D)g;
for (Line2D line : lines) {
    g2.draw(line);
}
```

Then you can just have a method to `addLine(Line2D line)`, which adds a line to the list and `repaint()`s

```
public void addLine(Line2D line) {
    lines.add(line);
    repaint();
}
```

---

> "how to draw graphics in JPanel out of paintComponent method?"

Don't. all custom painting should be done within the context of the `Graphics` object provided in the `paintComponent` method. So you need to anticipate what could possibly be drawn, and draw it. As seen above, this can be dynamic.

Comment: thx it worked well but when i remove some lines from the collection and i repaint it doesn't update the modifications any suggestions too ?

Comment: You need to make sure to call `super.paintComponent` inside the beginning of the `paintComponent` method